# How to enable mirroring option in airplay picker

Tags: iphone, mirroring, airplay

I added airplay picker functionality in app. Airplay picker shows only two option iphone and Apple TV doesn't shows Mirroring option. How can i show Mirroring option in the airplay picker so that app itself can be seen on Apple TV.

Please guide.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

It only works on the iPhone 4S and the iPad 2 and beyond. I had the same problem with my iPhone 4.

Answer (score 0):

No you havent the mirroring option. It is private API and some solution I found on github wasnt compatible to iOS 9.

I understand Apple that they want to protect the user with that only manually changeable switch.